# Generate Table (row and cells)

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have the VB.net code, but I need to convert it to VBScript. I need to open a word document count the tables and if there is a Word like (e.g. Tablein) I need to replace it with a table. But the table has to be built as the data is provided.

VB.net code (full code):

```
dim oRow As Word.Row,oTable As Word.Table
oRow = oTable.Rows(1)
oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = ""
If PullRow.Item("TYPE").ToString = "Traffic" Then
oRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = "T"
ElseIf PullRow.Item("TYPE").ToString = "Data" Then
oRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = "D"
End If
oRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = "C"
```

VBScript (Till I could write):

```vbs
Dim intNoOfRows

Dim intNoOfColumns

Dim objWord

Dim objDoc

Dim objRange

Dim objTable
dim strword

intNoOfRows = 5

intNoOfColumns = 3

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True    

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.open("new.docx")

g= objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.count

Set objRange = objDoc.Range

Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Borders.Enable = True   

With objWord.Selection
  .Find.Text = "pen"
  .Find.Forward = True
  .Find.MatchWholeWord = True
  Do
    found = .Find.Execute 

    If found Then objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 2,2
  Loop While found

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the table you created to a variable:

```
If found Then Set tbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, 2, 2)
```

Then use that variable to assign values to the table cells:

```
tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "foo"
tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = 23
tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "bar"
tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = 42
```

Comment: It is replacing the existing text in word document with "foo".I need to find a word, which is in a table and from then I need to add tables.if not skip it.Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to add a nested table inside a table cell?